# How to properly type a Redux connect call?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am trying to use a Redux state store in combination with TypeScript. I am trying to use the official Typings of Redux and want to make the entire call on the `connect` method (which connects the `mapStatetoProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` with a component) type safe.

I usually see approaches where the methods `mapStatetoProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` are just custom typed and return a partial of the component props, such as the following:

```
function mapStateToProps(state: IStateStore, ownProps: Partial<IComponentProps>)
  : Partial<IProjectEditorProps> {}
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch: Dispatch, ownProps: Partial<IComponentProps>)
  : Partial<IProjectEditorProps> {}
```

This is typed and works, but not really safe because it is possible to instantiate a component which misses props, as the usage of the Partial interface allows incomplete definitions. However, the Partial interface is required here because you may want to define some props in `mapStateToProps` and some in `mapDispatchToProps`, and not all in one function. So this is why I want to avoid this style.

What I am currently trying to use is directly embedding the functions in the `connect` call and typing the connect call with the generic typing supplied by redux:

```
connect<IComponentProps, any, any, IStateStore>(
  (state, ownProps) => ({
    /* some props supplied by redux state */
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    /* some more props supplied by dispatch calls */
  })
)(Component);
```

However, this also throws the error that the embedded  `mapStatetoProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` calls to not define *all* Props *each* as both only require a subset of them, but together defining all Props.

How can I properly type the connect call so that the  `mapStatetoProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` calls are really type safe and typing checks if the combined values defined by both methods supply all required props without one of the methods required to define all props at once? Is this somehow possible with my approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Option 1: Split `IComponentProps`

The simplest way to do this is probably just defining separate interfaces for your "state derived props", your "own props" and your "dispatch props" and then use an [intersection type](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-system.html#intersection-type) to join them together for the `IComponentProps`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect, Dispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { IStateStore } from '@src/reducers';


interface IComponentOwnProps {
  foo: string;
}

interface IComponentStoreProps {
  bar: string;
}

interface IComponentDispatchProps {
  fooAction: () => void;
}

type IComponentProps = IComponentOwnProps & IComponentStoreProps & IComponentDispatchProps

class IComponent extends React.Component<IComponentProps, never> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        foo: {this.props.foo}
        bar: {this.props.bar}
        <button onClick={this.props.fooAction}>Do Foo</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect<IComponentStoreProps, IComponentDispatchProps, IComponentOwnProps, IStateStore>(
  (state, ownProps): IComponentStoreProps => {
    return {
      bar: state.bar + ownProps.foo
    };
  },
  (dispatch: Dispatch<IStateStore>): IComponentDispatchProps => (
    {
      fooAction: () => dispatch({type:'FOO_ACTION'})
    }
  )
)(IComponent);
```

We can set the connect function generic parameters like so:
`<TStateProps, TDispatchProps, TOwnProps, State>`

### Option 2: Let your functions define your Props interface

Another option I've seen in the wild is to leveraging the [`ReturnType` mapped type](https://medium.com/@curtistatewilkinson/typescript-2-8-and-a-simple-example-of-returntype-ab454da83934) to allow your `mapX2Props` functions to actually define what they contribute to `IComponentProps`.

```
type IComponentProps = IComponentOwnProps & IComponentStoreProps & IComponentDispatchProps;

interface IComponentOwnProps {
  foo: string;
}

type IComponentStoreProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type IComponentDispatchProps = ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>;

class IComponent extends React.Component<IComponentProps, never> {
  //...
}


function mapStateToProps(state: IStateStore, ownProps: IComponentOwnProps) {
  return {
    bar: state.bar + ownProps.foo,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<IStateStore>) {
  return {
    fooAction: () => dispatch({ type: 'FOO_ACTION' })
  };
}

export default connect<IComponentStoreProps, IComponentDispatchProps, IComponentOwnProps, IStateStore>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(IComponent);
```

The big advantage here is that it reduces a little bit of the boiler plate and makes it so you only have one place to update when you add a new mapped prop.

I've always steered away from `ReturnType`, simplify because it feels backwards  to let your implementation define your programming interface "contracts" (IMO). It becomes almost *too easy* to change your `IComponentProps` in a way you didn't intend.

However, since everything here is pretty self contained, it's probably an acceptable use case.

Comment: So the ``connect`` call itself does not support a single state prop which checks both dispatch and store props? Would that generally be possible with a custom typing, checking for two distinct sets if they are disjunct and also define all required props, or is this not possible with TypeScript?

Comment: In theory it seems like you _should_ be able to do it.. However, I get an error when I try to set it up.  I've submitted an issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29399

Comment: Thanks, your approach looks like it should work like that. Marking this answer as accepted as the code in your answer seems to be the best approach currently possible.

Comment: @LukasBach thanks! I actually just added another option that I've seen in the past.  It's not personally the route I go, but you may like it better.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to split your component properties into state-, dispatch- and maybe own-properties:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { deleteItem } from "./action";
import { getItemById } from "./selectors";

interface StateProps {
  title: string;
}

interface DispatchProps {
  onDelete: () => any;
}

interface OwnProps {
  id: string;
}

export type SampleItemProps = StateProps & DispatchProps & OwnProps;

export const SampleItem: React.SFC<SampleItemProps> = props => (
  <div>
    <div>{props.title}</div>
    <button onClick={props.onDelete}>Delete</button>
  </div>
);

// You can either use an explicit mapStateToProps...
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState, ownProps: OwnProps) : StateProps => ({
  title: getItemById(state, ownProps.id)
});

// Ommitted mapDispatchToProps...

// ... and infer the types from connects arguments ...
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SampleItem);

// ... or explicitly type connect and "inline" map*To*.
export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps, RootState>(
  (state, ownProps) => ({
    title: getItemById(state, ownProps.id)
  }),
  (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    onDelete: () => dispatch(deleteItem(ownProps.id))
  })
)(SampleItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Really like @NSjonas's splitting approach, but I'd borrow something from his second approach as well to have a balance among practicality, not letting the implementation completely define your interface and not being extremely verbose in typing your dispatch actions;

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect, Dispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { IStateStore } from '@src/reducers';
import { fooAction } from '@src/actions';


interface IComponentOwnProps {
  foo: string;
}

interface IComponentStoreProps {
  bar: string;
}

interface IComponentDispatchProps {
  doFoo: (...args: Parameters<typeof fooAction>) => void;
}

type IComponentProps = IComponentOwnProps & IComponentStoreProps & IComponentDispatchProps

class IComponent extends React.Component<IComponentProps, never> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        foo: {this.props.foo}
        bar: {this.props.bar}
        <button onClick={this.props.doFoo}>Do Foo</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect<IComponentStoreProps, IComponentDispatchProps, IComponentOwnProps, IStateStore>(
  (state, ownProps): IComponentStoreProps => {
    return {
      bar: state.bar + ownProps.foo
    };
  },
  {
      doFoo: fooAction
  }
)(IComponent);
```